# Save to Excel during loop (Pandas DataFrame)

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am running a loop that creates a large nested dictionary and in the end, saves it to an excel file using pandas.

How do I save to the same excel file after X iterations instead of waiting until the end? For example for every 10th iteration? Is it possible?

Current code (simplified):

```python
import pandas as pd

d = {}

def some_function(x, y)
    d[x] = {'id': x, 'status': 'ok', 'info': y}
    ...
    print('ok')

elements = ['elem1', 'elem2', 'elem3', 'elem4', ..., 'elem1000']

count = 1

for element in elements:
    try:
        some_function(count, element)
    except:
        d[count] = {'id': count, 'status': 'error'}
    count += 1

df = pd.DateFrame(d).T
df.to_excel('output.xlsx', index=False)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, there's no good way to stream output to a single excel sheet with pandas. You can append the data as additional sheets using the pandas.ExcelWriter, but that doesn't sound like what you want.

You could always just run the df.to_excel every X iterations and overwrite the existing file, but that could get slow as your data gets large.

Comment: Overwriting the file after X iterations could be a solution. There are currently more than 2000 elements in the loop, so I am afraid the script will crash during runtime without saving anything at all. Overwriting after X iterations would be a clear improvement to not saving at all. :)